# Change VBA Word Word, to delete break of separate sections

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I got a VBA word on the internet to delete page sections in word, but the code deletes all section breaks of the entire document, I wanted to delete only the page selected separately from the others, what kind of change should I make in the code to execute this action?[image]

[image]

Comment: What does "page sections" mean? The `^b` stands for section break, while `^m` is for manual page breaks.

Comment: If you are already on the correct page, why not just delete the section break?

Comment: I can not delete section break, so I got a VBA code that does this while running it, however it deletes all section breaks of the entire document, I wanted to make it as exclude only the specified page by placing the cursor over the page to exclude

Comment: Is there a key that excludes the section break ?? because I can not delete any!

Comment: More info is needed. Is any part of the document protected? What happens when you try to delete a section break? You *are* viewing the document with paragraph marks and so on visible, right?

Comment: @cybernetic.normad, 
I do not know how to delete section break, just know how to delete page break

Comment: @cybernetic.normad, So far I could not delete section break

Comment: I have three section breaks and I can not delete any sections separately. I can only delete all together using VBA code, I wanted to exclude separately